# Loading a Pytorch model into C++ Using Dev Pytorch 1.0

Tags: pytorch

Pytorch 1.0 has a feature to convert a model into a torch script program (serialized in a way) to enable its execution in C++ without Python dependencies.

The details are in this tutorial. 
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_export.html

This is how it is done:

```
import torch
import torchvision

# An instance of your model.
model = A UNET MODEL FROM FASTAI which has hooks as required by UNET

# An example input you would normally provide to your model's forward() method.
example = torch.rand(1, 3, 224, 224)

# Use torch.jit.trace to generate a torch.jit.ScriptModule via tracing.
traced_script_module = torch.jit.trace(model, example)
```

In my use case, I am using a UNET Model for semantic segmentation. However, I trace the model using this method, I get the following error.

```
Forward or backward hooks can't be compiled
```

UNET Model uses hooks to save intermediate features which is used at later layers in the network. Is there a way around it? or This is still a limitation of this new method that it cannot work with Models using such hooks.

Comment: I wanted to use PyTorch to implement my model then after that load it to C++ though i did not find enough doc.examples that shows how to do so. Please I would be very grateful if you share ur experience. Like how you did solve this pb above ? did you find the loading process very diff ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the UNET model from Pytorch hub. It will work with TorchScript.

```
import torch

# downloading the model from torchhub
model = torch.hub.load('mateuszbuda/brain-segmentation-pytorch', 'unet',
    in_channels=3, out_channels=1, init_features=32, pretrained=True)

#  downloading the sample
import urllib
url, filename = ("https://github.com/mateuszbuda/brain-segmentation-pytorch/raw/master/assets/TCGA_CS_4944.png", "TCGA_CS_4944.png")
try: urllib.URLopener().retrieve(url, filename)
except: urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
    
# reading the sample and some prerequisites for transformation
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import transforms

input_image = Image.open(filename)

m, s = np.mean(input_image, axis=(0, 1)), np.std(input_image, axis=(0, 1))
preprocess = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),transforms.Normalize(mean=m, std=s),])

input_tensor = preprocess(input_image)

input_batch = input_tensor.unsqueeze(0)

# creating the trace
traced_module = torch.jit.trace(model,input_batch)

# running the trace
traced_module(input_batch)
```

PS: Both torch.jit.trace/torch.jit.script does not support all torch functionality, so there is always tricky to use them with external libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you could rewrite the model in C++, since c++ API has almost the same interface as python version.